# Configure an Activiti BPM?

Tags: grails, groovy, activiti

I want to know that how to configure/run Activiti BPM in Grails?? I'm using fedora as my OS, Grails 2.1 . If their is any tutorial websites are is plz mention it also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Grails applications that provides much of Activiti within a Grails app. http://grails.org/plugin/activiti However, development has sadly stopped on it by the main developer. The last update was for Activiti 5.9 and Grails 2.1, though much of the plugin content seems to be built for older versions of Grails; for example, actions in the plugin's TaskController are all closures, not methods. Also, someone did issue a pull request to update it to 5.10.

I've been trying to puzzle through the source for that plugin myself. I keep vacillating between simply setting up a standalone Activiti server and utilizing the RESTful API from within a Grails Service class, importing a few of the Activiti classes into my Grails app, or trying to re-engineer the plugin to suit my needs (my site is stuck on Grails 2.0.1 for the time being).